# Math equations in Impress

Tags: libreoffice

I made an Impress presentation and saved it as PowerPoint. Then, in PowerPoint, I added an equation to one of the text boxes. Back in Impress, I can see the text and equation just like in PowerPoint, but I can no longer edit the text.

My questions are:

- How can I recover the text from the textbox with the equation?
- How can I write a math equation in Impress in a cross-platform manner?